# How to dynamically declare an instance variable?

Tags: java, class, variables, instance, declaration

I have the following class:

```
public class MotherFactory {

    private String food = "banana";

    private static FoodFactory<Banana> foodFactory = new BananaFactory();

    public MotherFactory() {        
    }
}
```

In this class i declare a FoodFactory for BananaHsm, which i hardcoded in (The food string has no use in this yet). What i want however, is that the declaration of the FoodFactory changes according to the food String. E.g.: For `private String food = "apple"`, `<BananaFactory>` changes to `<AppleFactory>`, and `new BananaFactory()` to `new AppleFactory` and so on. i already thought of using a switch or if/else, however these would be declared inside the constructor, which doesnt make the variables usable for the whole instance.
Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: You would make a FoodFactory with a static method ``getFactory(String food)`` that returns the appropiate factory.

Comment: And use a `Map<String, FoodFactory<? extends Food>>` to avoid a long if/else or switch.

Comment: @f1sh wouldnt this only be possible when FoodFactory didnt need the type? e.g.: '<Banana>' or 'Apple'? Also i cant edit the FoodFactory Class.

Comment: See [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: You  may actually prefer creating a `FruitFactory` which will accept a fruit string (or an enum if your purpose allows it) in the argument of a method `function Fruit createFruit(String fruit)`

Comment: Create an interface Fruit; have all you fruits implement Fruit. (Sorry, comments don't format.) Create a FruitFactory with a method public <T extends Fruit> T createFruit(Class<T> fruitClass) { return fruitClass.newInstance() }. This should be a good starting point.